# converting text file into xml using php?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, text-files

data.txt

```
ha15rs,250,home2.gif,2
ha36gs,150,home3.gif,1
ha27se,300,home4.gif,4
ha4678,200,home5.gif,5
```

i want convert this textfile into xml using simplexml module using php? thanks :))

p.s. im new to this

EDIT:

```
<allproperty>
          <aproperty>
                   <postcode></postcode>
                   <price></price>
                   <imagefilename></imagefilename>
                   <visits></visits>
              </aproperty>
              <aproperty>
                   <postcode></postcode>
                   <price></price>
                   <imagefilename></imagefilename>
                   <visits></visits>
              </aproperty>
              <aproperty>
                   <postcode></postcode>
                   <price></price>
                   <imagefilename></imagefilename>
                   <visits></visits>
              </aproperty>
          </allproperty>
```

Comment: Start: `file()` to parse the file into lines; `explode()` to split up the columns

Comment: Then put together a DOMDocument: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933563/creating-dynamic-xml-with-php and write it out into a file

Comment: My mind-reading is a little slow today.  Could you just tell us what format you want it in?  Thx.

Comment: @Pekka: The OP specifically asked for SimpleXML.

Comment: xml file :)) @jonah bron

Comment: @getaway: No, how do you want it?  What tag names?

Comment: let me update my answer sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I think [XMLWriter](http://php.net/XMLWriter) is best suited for that task ([like in my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445825/converting-text-file-into-xml-using-php/4445891#4445891)), if you really want to do it with SimpleXML, here's how:

```
$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'r');

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<allproperty></allproperty>');

while ($line = fgetcsv($fp)) {
   if (count($line) < 4) continue; // skip lines that aren't full

   $node = $xml->addChild('aproperty');
   $node->addChild('postcode', $line[0]);
   $node->addChild('price', $line[1]);
   $node->addChild('imagefilename', $line[2]);
   $node->addChild('visits', $line[3]);
}

echo $xml->saveXML();
```

You will notice that the output is not as clean: it's because SimpleXML doesn't allow you to automatically indent tags.

Comment: thanks your a star!!!! sorry about that, im a pian in the ass, anyhow +1 from me again and right answer :))

Answer (score 4):

I will suggest you to use [XMLWriter](http://php.net/XMLWriter) instead, because it is best suited for that (and it's also built-in like SimpleXML):

```
$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'r');

$xml = new XMLWriter;
$xml->openURI('php://output');
$xml->setIndent(true); // makes output cleaner

$xml->startElement('allproperty');
while ($line = fgetcsv($fp)) {
   if (count($line) < 4) continue; // skip lines that aren't full

   $xml->startElement('aproperty');
   $xml->writeElement('postcode', $line[0]);
   $xml->writeElement('price', $line[1]);
   $xml->writeElement('imagefilename', $line[2]);
   $xml->writeElement('visits', $line[3]);
   $xml->endElement();
}
$xml->endElement();
```

Of course, you can change the `php://output` argument to a filename if you want it to output to a file.

Comment: im trying to learn with simplexml, i love your code though!! cheers